# How do I move the camera sideways in Libgdx?

Tags: camera, libgdx

I want to move the camera sideways (strafe). I had the following in mind, but it doesn't look like there are standard methods to achieve this in Libgdx.

If I want to move the camera sideways by x, I think I need to do the following:

1. Create a Matrix4 `mat`
2. Determine the orthogonal vector v between `camera.direction` and `camera.up`
3. Translate `mat` by `v*x`
4. Multiply `camera.position` by `mat`

Will this approach do what I think it does, and is it a good way to do it?
And how can I do this in libgdx? I get "stuck" at step 2, as I have not found any standard method in Libgdx to calculate an orthogonal vector.

EDIT: I think I can use `camera.direction.crs(camera.up)` to find `v`. I'll try this approach tonight and see if it works.

EDIT2: I got it working and didn't need the matrix after all:

```
Vector3 right = camera.direction.cpy().crs(camera.up).nor();
camera.position.add(right.mul(x));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll do what you think it does. If you check the `Camera` class [source code](http://code.google.com/searchframe#c5txscj0tnc/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.java), you'll see that they're doing exactly what you suggest, plus they're normalizing the result:

```
93 final Vector3 right = new Vector3();
94
95 public void normalizeUp () {
96     right.set(direction).crs(up).nor();
97     (...)
98 }
```

The "standard" method of finding a vector orthogonal to two others is indeed to compute their [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) (in libgdx or anywhere).

There's an additional benefit of knowing this: if you're sure that `normalizeUp()` gets called in your case, you can just use `camera.right` directly, e.g.:

```
camera.position += camera.right * someFactor;
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it working, i came to the same conclusion a few moments ago, that i didn't really need the matrix if i had the `right` vector. I have to create my own `right` though, as it is private field. I've updated my question with the code i'm using now.

Comment: Have you thought about using TweenEngine to move cameras?  It can let you do some really cool effects with the camera. http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2011/04/java-universal-tween-engine/

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean forward = false;
boolean back = false;
boolean right = false;
boolean left = false;

// when WASD keys are pressed, turn booleans on/off
// call this on create()
// you didn't ask for but I also included the relation between mouse and cam
// if you have a camera controller, please delete mouse moved function.
// also don't forget to override other methods.
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
        private int dragX, dragY;
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            switch (keycode) {
            case (Input.Keys.W):
                forward = true;
                break;
            case (Input.Keys.A):
                left = true;
                break;
            case (Input.Keys.S):
                back = true;
                break;
            case (Input.Keys.D):
                right = true;
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            switch (keycode) {
            case (Input.Keys.W):
                forward = false;
                break;
            case (Input.Keys.A):
                left = false;
                break;
            case (Input.Keys.S):
                back = false;
                break;
            case (Input.Keys.D):
                right = false;
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            Vector3 direction = cam.direction.cpy();

            float x = dragX -screenX;
            cam.rotate(Vector3.Y,x/5.0f);

            float y = dragY -screenY;
            cam.direction.y +=   Math.sin( y/180f) ;

            cam.update();
            dragX = screenX;
            dragY = screenY;
            return true;
        }

    });

// call on render() or anywhere you see fit.
public void walking () {
    if (forward) {
        Vector3 v = cam.direction.cpy();
        v.y=0f;
        cam.translate(v);
        cam.update();
    }
    if (back) {
        Vector3 v = cam.direction.cpy();
        v.y=0f;
        v.x = - v.x;
        v.z = - v.z;
        cam.translate(v);
        cam.update();
    }
    if (left) {
        Vector3 v = cam.direction.cpy();
        v.y=0f;
        v.rotate(Vector3.Y, 90);
        cam.translate(v);
        cam.update();
    }
    if (right) {
        Vector3 v = cam.direction.cpy();
        v.y=0f;
        v.rotate(Vector3.Y, -90);
        cam.translate(v);
        cam.update();
    }
}
```

In this case you need to multiply the `Vector3 v` with the value of x. You can multiply x, y, z one by one, right before the translation.
One other thing, My up is Y axis but of course yours is probably dynamic.  SO instead of using `Vector3.Y`, please use `cam.up`. I am not sure it will work, but please Experiment.
And most importantly have a nice day.